# Spatial join loads indefinitely in QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, ram

I am trying to perform a spatial join between a very large polygon layer and a very large point layer in QGIS. I left the process running overnight but there does not appear to be any sign of progress. I thought it might be an issue with my CPU or RAM but when I open task manager QGIS is only using 266% of the CPU and the memory is only 35%.

Has anyone else experienced a similar problem and if so has anyone solved it?

Comment: What is "very large"? 266%? Do the layers have a spatial index? How complex are the polygons?

Comment: A bit more context could help understanding the problem.

Comment: When I perform the spatial join it says there is no spatial index. The polygon layer is 396.25 MB and has a feature count of 136,903. The point layer is 58.44 MB and has a feature count of 95,174.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem was that a software problem called docker was running in the background even though it was not saying so in task manager. Once I uninstalled it, the spatial join worked perfectly.